# How can I decrease the time it takes CentOS to discover new USB devices?

Tags: usb, centos, kvm-switch

I have two systems sharing a KVM.  The first system is Ubuntu 12.04 and the second system is CentOS 5.8.  When I switch to the the Ubuntu system, the mouse is available right away, but when I switch to the CentOS system, it takes about 10 seconds for the mouse to be available.

Do you have any suggestions wrt decreasing the 10s time it takes CentOS to find the mouse ?

I'm just looking to decrease the time it takes CentOS to find new USB devices in general, so I don't think setting "options usbhid mousepoll=2" is the right answer.

Thanks !